# How do I permanently boot up from previous version

Tags: boot, grub2, data-recovery

Excuse my ignorance here, I have been using Ubuntu on my surface pro 3, Not dual boot, to learn ROS which only runs on `16.04 LTS`. Everything has been working for the most part

But last night I was prompted to install a lot of updates to some packages and so I did. I kept using the laptop and didn't reboot.

Today when I turn the laptop on, it is all out of whack and the Bluetooth mouse is not picked up, the attached keyboard doesn't work. and screen resolution is really low.

So I reboot and press shift and boot up a previous version `4.8.0-49` and works flawless, question is how do I make it keep these settings as oppose to the new `4.8.0-51` settings.

In other words make it boot up to this version instead of the whatever happened after the update.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions around your issue, here is some of them which I would do:

First of all as you saw yourself, the old kernel still lives in your system. you can set that entry in `grub` as your default entry;

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

the `GRUB_DEFAULT`'s value should be changed to something like `"2>3"`, `2`: sub-menu number (Advanced Ubuntu options), `3`: Old kernel entry number in sub-menu.

then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

The alternative to this solution is that, instead of `"x>y"` use `saved` there and then after saving the file, run:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-set-default
```

First time that you select the old kernel, it will be saved; And next time it's the default selection (Not sure if it works for sub menus).

You can also remove the running version and run `update-grub` again or even create a custom menu and disable others.

At the end you can use `apt-mark` to hold your desired kernel version.

Comment: You are welcome, which of the instructions did you use?

Comment: Won't this boot to the recently installed  not working kernel after the next kernel update as menu-entries will be regenerated? I think better to use the name of the menu-entry or the menu-entry identifier to avoid this.

Comment: Yeah I guess,  that would be better. although I prefer to create a custom menu entry and set that as default.

Comment: @EdwinFairchild Please consider to accept and/or upvote Ravexina's answer as it solved your problem. This would be the best way to say thank you.